# how to find shared library path in java without using LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: java

I want to load so file "libhello.so" with java, for some reasons, i can't change  LD_LIBRARY_PATH in redhat, the .so file "libhello.so" is in /home/arthur/lib, how can i load this so file? below is the sample code:

```
class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
System.load("/home/arthur/lib/libhello.so");
```